# Trigger error from external functionality to Jquery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to invalidate my password field if **password strength** is weak.

I am using "pstrength" method to calculate password strength.

Bar below password input box changes color as password strength increases.

I am using jQuery Validation plugin to validate rest of my form fields which is working fine.

I need to trigger error messages if password is weak , say if strength is less than 30 count(e.g. in fiddle) and strength bar color is yellow or green.

I have added fiddle for the same [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XN8DJ/4/)

**addMethod** will add new validation method but actually i need to trigger error from external functionality "pStrength" when passwordStrength is lower than expected

I tried to call it as for e.g.

```
if(passwordStrength < 30){

            var $validator = jQuery("#registerForm").validate();
            $validator.showErrors("password strength is low");

        }
```

But no luck

Comment: This makes no sense.  "external functionality"?  You would put this external functionality into the `addMethod()` function and that would trigger your errors.

Comment: You may not realize it, but you are asking how to create a custom rule for the jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [addMethod](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to validate the password strength with `checkPassword`. So you can do something like this:

```
var options = {
    verdicts: ["Very Weak", "Weak", "Medium", "Strong", "Very Strong"],
    colors: ["#f00","#c06", "#f60","#3c0","#3f0"],
    scores: [10,15,30,40],
    minchar: 8
};
jQuery.validator.addMethod("passwordStrength", function(val, el, param) {
    return jQuery.fn.checkPassword(val, options) > param;
}, "password strength is too low");
```

Comment: This could cause me entire logic change .Thats why i am looking for external function call .

Comment: This is how you would do it!

Comment: Thats a way, i know but i was looking for if possible to call validation from other functions.